# PHP regular expression skip element

Tags: php, regex

I have written regular expression which converts text links into clickable link. The code works fine however when an HTML tag  is passed it mess the code

Here is my code

```
$text = preg_replace('#(?<![">])((http|ftp)s?://[^<>\s]+)#i', '<a href="\\0">\\0</a>', $text );
```

It is suppose to skip following element

```
<a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</a>
```

but it does not.. what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show an element that should be replaced as well?

Comment: it converts url like http://yahoo.com to <a href="http://yahoo.com">http://yahoo.com</a>

What I am trying to do is to skip the <a href tags

Comment: Use the PHP DOM functions to only apply the regex to text nodes that are not within A tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking your code with two inputs:

```
$text1 = '<a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</a>';
$text2 = 'text text http://www.yahoo.com text';

$reg = '{
         (?<![">])
         (
           (?:http|ftp)s? : // [^<>\s]+
         )
        }ix';

echo  preg_replace($reg, '<A HREF="\1">\1</A>', $text1 ) . "\n";
echo  preg_replace($reg, '<A HREF="\1">\1</A>', $text2 ) . "\n";
```

and reading the corresponding outputs:

```
=> #1 not touched  <a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</a>
=> #2 modified     text text <A HREF="http://www.yahoo.com">http://www.yahoo.com</A> text
```

I'd ask you what you think what should be different?

Regards

rbo

Comment: #1 should output like <a href=" <a href="http://www.yahoo.com/"">http://www.yahoo.com/"</a>>Yahoo</a>

Comment: There was space after <a href="<SPACE> so the rule was ignoring it. I added \s and its working now

Answer (score 1):

It does skip it. `"` is before the URL, so the negative look behind makes it not match.

Anyway, to do this reliably, you should be using a HTML parser. You could transform only text nodes not worrying about existing HTML elements.